# Selecting only few files from large no of files in a directory/bash script

Tags: bash

I have a very simple question, I have 10,000 files in a directory with the name `simulations_0.root` to `simulations_9999.root`.

I want to merge 500 files together to make them bigger in size. I need to run `hadd`, selecting `simulations_0.root` to `simulations_499.root`; `simulations_500.root` to `simulations_999.root` and so on.

`hadd` will take multiple input files as command line arguments:

```
Synopsis
hadd outputfile inputfiles ...
```

My question is how can I select those files from 0 to 500 at once in the `hadd` command?

Comment: `mkdir -p concat_500 && printf '%s\0' simulations_*.root | sort -z -t_ -k2n | xargs -0 -n 500 sh -c 'hadd "concat_500/$1" "$@"' _`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @mashuptwice method a little further:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

min=0 max=9999 incr=500

for (( i = min, j = min + incr - 1; j <= max; i += incr, j+= incr))
do
    declare -a "files=( simulations_{$i..$j}.root )"
    hadd "simulations_${i}to$j.root" "${files[@]}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked, one minor change needed was : hadd "simulations_$i-$j.root" "${files[@]}" instead of hadd "simulations_${i}to$j.root" "${files[@]}"

Answer (score 1):

You can use brace expansions for that.

**Example:**

```
[user@host dir]$ bash -x
[user@host dir]$ echo foo{1..10}
+ echo foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5 foo6 foo7 foo8 foo9 foo10
foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5 foo6 foo7 foo8 foo9 foo10
```

As you can see in the above example with `bash -x`, the expression `foo{1..10}` will get expanded into space separated arguments.

In your particular case the command would be:

```
hadd output_file.root simulations_{1..500}.root
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!